# Get multiple users from facebook open graph with one call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Calling this URL return a user object with public informations about a facebook user:
https://graph.facebook.com/100000050972893

100000050972893 is the facebook user ID. Is it possible to get multiple user objects with one call? I need to know the gender of about 200 users and I dont think its a good idea calling 200 times the graph URL...

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer:

https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=100000050972893,100000953354280

But I dont know where the Limit of IDs is you can check with one call...

Comment: In the documentation, they have not mentioned about any limit. You can test and may be post here :)

Comment: Looks like a Limit of 5000 users on page 1, but its with pagination